# How to update inside the array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Here i want to write the update query like inside tags array suppose value is `good` i want to change `very-good`.i had written but is not working properly,suppose insdie `tags` two value is there means , two values itself getting updated

> my documents

```
    /* 1 createdAt:12/18/2018, 5:59:33 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e82da073cdc5c70072dc"),
    "roleID" : "3",
    "tags" : [
        "good"
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:12/18/2018, 5:59:33 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e82da073cdc5c70072db"),
    "roleID" : "2",
    "tags" : [
        "very-good",
        "good"
    ]
},
```

Comment: what you get after run ther query?

Comment: Is `options-short` always in the first position?

Comment: @Prasanna I have added a simple solution for you, using `updateMany` instead of `update` with `{"multi": true}`

Answer (score 1):

This code worked perfectly, it uses `updateMany` instead of just `update`. This code uses the **$ operator**:

### Code

```js
db.QuestionContents.updateMany({contentID: {$in: contentID}, tags: "options-short"}, {$set: {"tags.$": "options-2x2"}});
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

### Output

Here is the result of `db.QuestionContents.find({})`:

[image: Output]

Comment: @Prasanna if my answer worked for you, please, mark it as accepted (green checkmark). Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to update -

```
db.QuestionContents.update({contentID: {$in: contentID}, tags: "options-short" }, {$set:{"tags.$":"options-short2*2"}},{"multi": true});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html#up._S_addToSet) with [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/index.html#up._S_each)

```
db.QuestionContents.update({contentID: {$in: contentID} }, {$addToSet:{tags:{
  $each:["options-2x2"]}}},{"multi": true});
```

Comment: it is not updating, it is inserting the inside the array, it has to update